# My USB network adapter is slow ONLY on my laptop. I've tried everything

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, usb, drivers, usb-3

I've encountered an issue and I've exhausted all my options, so I'm posting here. This has really got me confused and I'd love to know the answer.

I have a Windows 10 Inspiron 15 7559. The onboard network card broke a while back, so I purchased a TP-LINK TL-WN823N 300Mbps to connect to Wifi. I clock around 13mbps download speed. I plugged it into my wife's laptop, connect to same network- she gets a nice 70mbps d/l speed.

I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling the TP Link drivers. The only reason I can deduce is maybe something is wrong with my USB ports? The laptop has 3 USB ports, all 3.0 and one USB 3.0 w/ PowerShare. I've tried all ports, tested speed- all the same.

The USB controller is Intel USB 3.0 extensible host controller 1.0. I read that there are no drivers for this controller for Windows 10 (even though this computer came as Windows 10).

I'd greatly appreciate any ideas or input!

Thanks!